# Provisioning desktop fails with App-v 4.5 client

Tags: vmware-view

Has anybody tried to provision a Windows desktop with App-v 4.5 client in the image?

I've tried it with Windows XP and 7 but after creating the desktop pool, provisioning fails.
In the View Manager I see an error: `View Composer agent initialization state error (6): Unknown failure (waited 0 seconds)`.
We are using View 4 and also checked Vmware KB: 1011653.

The App-v 4.5 client was installed before the View Agent.

Comment: Why aren't you running the 4.6 client?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this exact issue.  I've posted about it and found a workaround.
http://tech.zsoldier.com/2010/03/view-composer-agent-initialization.html

Comment: It is much preferably to add a full solution as an answer, not a mere link to a blog that may or may not be around in a few years. Even if you can guarantee that the site and article will be around for the long term, it is still frowned upon to provide a link as an answer. ServerFault is concerned with being where the actual answer is found, not just links to answers.